# Self is required as an argument

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working with kivy on python2.7. As far as I know, self is not a real argument but a tool to use in the function, when working with the parent data. Yet in the following use, python thinks self is a real argument. Is this because I'm calling it in the function?

```
class Verdo(BoxLayout):
    defualtval = ""
    tarih = StringProperty(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0])
    istipitxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    iscitxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    iskodtxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    baslabittxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    parcanotxt = StringProperty(defualtval)



    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.5)

    def callback(self, dt):
        print "testo"
        self.tarih = StringProperty(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0])

    start()   
    #Clock.schedule_interval((lambda dt: updater(), 1), 0.5)   
    #Clock.schedule_interval((lambda dt: tell(), 1), 0.5)
```

When the code is run, following error happens:

```
2015-04-07 22:05:03.081739
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/toshy/workspace/Verdo_reborn/main.py", line 28, in <module>
     class Verdo(BoxLayout):
   File "/home/toshy/workspace/Verdo_reborn/main.py", line 79, in Verdo
     start()   
 TypeError: start() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I also tried an simpler approach which also failed:

```
def callback(self, dt):
    print "testo"
    self.tarih = StringProperty(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0])

Clock.schedule_interval(callback, 0.5)
```

output:

```
     ret = callback(self._dt)
 TypeError: callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Is your indentation right? In your example you are calling start() without an object (e.g. `x.start()`).

Comment: The problem I'm having is the classes are called by the kivy mainloop, that is why I'm trying to get the function run in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
class Verdo(BoxLayout):
    defualtval = ""
    tarih = StringProperty(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0])
    istipitxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    iscitxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    iskodtxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    baslabittxt = StringProperty(defualtval)
    parcanotxt = StringProperty(defualtval)



    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.5)

    def callback(self, dt):
        print "testo"
        self.tarih = StringProperty(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0])    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    verdoInstance = Verdo()
    verdoInstance.start()
```

This is just an example, if you want test your code quickly as a single executable python script.
Your error was you tried to call your class method without calling constructor right in your class code. In this case method class really was waiting self (object ref) as a first argument, but the object wasn`t created at that time.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling:

```
 self.start()
```

`self` *is* a real argument, but it's supplied automatically as the object on which the method was called.

There are two different contexts in which you might want to call `.start()`.  The first is after instantiating an object of type Verdo:

```
 my_verdo = Verdo()
 my_verdo.start()
```

Alternatively, you may be calling from *inside* the code for Verdo.  In that case you need to specify that your're operating on the current instance.

Comment: He should not be calling "start" from within the class body.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the intention is.  I could more accurately have written "If you are attempting to call start from within the class definition of Verdo, you should write. . . ".

Comment: Still, trying to call an instance method from the class body which defines it in Python is wrong in at least 3 different ways. And that code is in the question, and you don't clarify it - you just list `self.start` out of any context. In the class body, that would fail with "NameError" to start with.